# Layers in physics or what is it (look at the image)?

Tags: lua, box2d, coronasdk

[image]

I need to move an object on track when obj getting into track, but at the same time, it could easily pass under it.

I don't know how it called. And I'm looking for name of this procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know there is no simple way of making one object collide with another and later to suppress this behavior.

I suggest re-creating this part of a track with categoryBits, maskBits set accordingly (or isSensor=true flag to turn off the collisions with this object) when the vehicle changes its virtual altitude.

http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/game-edition-collision-detection

Answer (score 0):

If you are using physics to detect the collision you could just remove the object (train, car, ball, what ever is supposed to go under the track) from physics to avoid a collision and then re-add it once you the object passes under the track.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the order of your object displaying. As far as I know the order in which variables are declared sets up who takes precedence over the other.

For setting up the collision (in order to avoid hitting each other) just use the categoryBits and maskBits.

Answer (score 0):

As atok said, I'm pretty sure that there isn't any way to set collision masks after you've called physics.addBody() on a DisplayObject.
There's a wonderful guide on collision filters (using categoryBits and maskBits) [here](http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2010/10/25/collision-filters-helper-chart), and the docs for physics.addBody are [here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/addBody.html). There's also some other stuff on it [here](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/game-edition-collision-detection#Collision_categories_masking_and_groups).